# show that a functional operator $F : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continous

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

i have the following homework:

Let $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continous and $X = C([a,b])$ with the metric
$$
 d(x,y) := \sup_{t \in [a,b]} |x(t) - y(t)|
$$
show that $F: X \to \mathbb{R}$ with
$$
  F(x) = \int_a^b g(x(t)) \mathrm{d}t
$$
is a continous function.

I was able to show a much weaker proposition, namely that the functional
$$
  F'(f) = \int_a^b f(t) \mathrm{d}t
$$
is uniformly continous.

My proof: For $\varepsilon > 0$, set $\delta := \frac{\varepsilon}{b-a}$, if $d(f,g) < \delta$ then
\begin{align*}
  |F'(f) - F'(g)| & = | \int_a^b f(t) \mathrm{d}t - \int_a^b g(t) \mathrm{d}t| \\
                  & = | \int_a^b f(t) - g(t) \mathrm{d}t | \\
                  & \le \int_a^b |f(t) - g(t)| \mathrm{d}t \\
                  & \le \int_a^b \delta \mathrm{d}t \\
                  & = \delta \cdot (b-a) = \varepsilon
\end{align*}
But i am not able to generalize my results, do you have any hints for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a convergent series in $X$. Since convergence in $X$ is pointwise convergence (due to the use of the supremum norm), and since $g$ is continous, you have $$
  g\left(\left(\lim_{i\to\infty}x_i\right)(t)\right) = \lim_{i \to \infty} g(x_i(t)) \text{ for every } t \in [a,b]
$$

Now, all $x \in X$ are uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ because they are continous and $[a,b]$ is compact. Also, every convergent series in $X$ must be bounded, i.e. if $\lim_{i\to\infty}x_i = x$, there is a compact set $K$ with $\text{ran }x_i \subset K$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, you may replace $g$ with $g|_K$ ($g$ restricted to $K$), which is then uniformly continous, again because it's continous on a compact set. Together, you get that the limit converges uniformly (wrt $t$), which should be sufficient to swap it with the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $g$ is uniformly continuous on the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: This could be misinterpreted, because there are a fixed $a$ and $b$ in the problem, and $g$'s behavior on that particular interval isn't most relevant.